# Are there any drawbacks that should hold you from adding an index to a table column?

Tags: sql, database

I've faced this problem two times over the last two weeks: I have to query a huge database, looking for some entries based on a non-numeric field. The problem is that there are no indexes for such fields, so, my query is taking ~40 min to find results (because I limited it to get the only the first 20).

When I asked my co-workers why there is no index on the field, they said that there's no way of guessing *a priori* which fields will require an index, so, no index was created.

When I asked them to create a new index for me, they said that this cannot be done in production, they'd have to create a test environment, create the index, see how it behaves and only then put this in production. This was considered too much work, unworthed, so, I'm still stuck.

I'm no database expert, but, as far as I know, a new index will only impact the size of the dabatase, nothing else. Am I wrong?

In other words: Why shoul I **not** create an index on every column that **might** be a filtering or sorting factor? And why can I not add an index to a production database?

Comment: Do you have many inserts or updates in you table?Many indexes can slow down these operations.But indexes on production databases are generally not only recommended but many times a necessity.

Comment: You'll also have to update the index every time you insert/remove/update a record, and depending on the frequency of access this could become much more expensive than your once-in-a-lifetime select on a rarely queried field.  Perhaps you should be doing this on a (reporting) copy of the database?

Comment: For what I'm doing, no, just selecting data, but this database is the warehouse for a IBM ObjectServer that monitors events over a network. There's a heavy use of inserts and updates.

Comment: Indexes aren't free or the RDBMS would just make them for you on every column. Indexes make reads faster at the expense of slower writes.

Comment: Depending your DBMS the table might be locked completely while the index is built (at least for writes, some DBMS even block that for reads). So this is not something that you should do without planning on a production server.

Comment: Tables that store event data are very sensitive to any slow-downs in write-performance.  Perhaps you need to find a different strategy to get at your data..

Comment: The write frequency is 2 minutes. Every two minutes, the Object Server dumps (by blocks) some data into this Oracle database.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons your co-workers won't allow you to add an index on the production database is because adding an index has a cost. It will take a lot of time analyzing an index on a big table.

However as you have already signaled, the index comes with a lot of benefits, so I don't think you should be worrying about the time it takes the rdbms to analyze the table. Adding indexes on columns that are searchable and/or joinable will almost always be a recommended practice, no matter what your co-workers say.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I have no authority to change this =/

Answer (score 1):

Technically, adding an index *could* slow down updates to the table, or change execution plans, or add overhead when creating the index. In reality though it's doubtful that a simple index would have much of an effect. You're dealing with a political issue, not a technical one.

Comment: I have an information that this table is updated every 2 minutes with new and updated data. Could an extra index impact the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Other drawback of adding index to production database is lock on database during its creation (so no new inserts) and longer inserts/updates - every time that data are changed every index need to be updated.

Maybe one time analytical query is not worth a downtime?